# How to execute a tcl script from php via logging into another server

Tags: php, ssh, tcl

I am working on a project where from my front-end (written in php) needs to login to a server and execute a tcl script which can run only in that server.

So first I would like to generate a connection first and then execute the tcl in that established connection.

I am not able to generate a connection to the server.

My php script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php

        function print_procedure ($arg) {
            $array = array();
            echo exec('/usr/bin/tclsh ./$args',$array);

            for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
            {
                echo "<br>";
                print_r($array[$i]);
                echo "<br>";
            }
            $script_name='test.tcl';
        }
        print_procedure($script_name);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/ ?

Comment: Yes this might be useful, will give it a try... But it would be better to prefer ssh connectivity ....

Comment: As we prefer connecting to the said server via ssh rather than telnet....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to use `ssh` in its "run a remote command" mode.

```
echo exec('ssh $remotehost /usr/bin/tclsh ./$args', $array);
```

This assumes that the script has already been uploaded to the remote host. If not, do that first with `scp` (a part of the same suite of programs as `ssh`).

You'll then *need* to configure the account running that PHP script to be able to ssh to the remote host without entering a password. A reasonably secure method is to set up `ssh-agent` with a key, but I do not know the details of making this method work with PHP. (Turning off passwords on the target machine would also work, but is *scary* in security terms!)

Comment: In general, this is just running _any_ program remotely with _ssh_; there are no Tcl-specific details to look out for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me out. I am using an alias at $remotehost, i.e, a name instead of server ip. But am not able to make it execute. When I issue "whoami" i still see it as apache. Are there any prerequisites to do before issuing the ssh from php.?

Comment: @Harsh Nothing specific. You might need to use `user@host` as the pattern to connect to, but the details of that are very specific to your setup. Also, any general advice on using ssh will apply; this is 99% an ssh question, 1% a PHP question, and not a Tcl question at all. The Tcl bits happen after all the bits you seem to be having problems with...

Comment: Hi @Donal Fellows, I searched over net and found a solution and installed ssh2. I followed this procedure [link]http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php 

I then issued the following
    if (!($connection = ssh2_connect('server_name', 22))) {
        print_r("hi");
    } else {
        print_r("connected");
    }
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user_name', 'password');
`code`
I even tried
`code`
    echo exec('ssh $remotehost /usr/bin/tclsh ./$args', $array);
`code`
But whenever my script see a line with ssh in it, the ouput page becomes complete blank.

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend you use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ . It works a ton better than the PECL ssh2 installation.